# Regexmatch in Google Sheet to find 2 sections of my website

Tags: regex, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, spreadsheet

I'm trying to find the number of users coming to 2 different parts of my website:

- /blog/
- resources.company

To do this I use REGEXMATCH with `|` separator:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(('raw data'!$B$2:$B),REGEXMATCH('RAW - New Users'!$A$2:$A,"/blog/|resources.company"))
```

However, when I check with this formula:

```
  =SUMPRODUCT(('raw data'!$B$2:$B),REGEXMATCH('RAW - New Users'!$A$2:$A,"/blog/") + REGEXMATCH('RAW - New Users'!$A$2:$A,"resources.company"))
```

I find more users.

I'm pretty sure the `.` messes up with the 1st formula. I've tried `/blog/|resources\.company` but it didn't help. How can I change my first formula so the REGEXMATCH finds everything that contains "resources.company" as well as "/blog"?

Comment: Is this a matter of **and** or **or**? I mean, the 1st formula does only count each cell once if either of the two alternatives is present (or both). The 2nd formula would count each cell double if both alternatives are present, possibly resulting in false information.

Comment: @JvdV it's a matter of OR. I was sure the 1st formula was the wrong one since it was missing some new users. But you are right, 2nd formula is counting information twice in case both occurrences appear. Thank you so much for your clear and fast answer.

Comment: Please share a copy / sample of your sheet with an example of the desired output. Whenever possible, you need to include a minimal example that reproduces the issue. You can also include the expected behavior, the actual behavior, and how they differ, that would be helpful as well. Please visit [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) have some tips on how to write a question, so the community will be able to help you out in a better way.

Comment: @Lorena Gomez Hi, JvdV already answered my question. I wasn't able to validate his answer since it was a comment though.